# Stop periodic service in Android

Tags: android, service

I have created a service in android that is called periodically after approximately 3 minutes
the service is started successfully  but I'm unable to stop it :S
I have written these codes for start and stop services , can anyoe help me why the stop function doesn't stop the service.

```
    public void startService()
    {`enter code here`

    //////////for location  
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Close_Bus.this, gps.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Close_Bus.this, 0,    myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                   // 3 miniutes
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 180000, pendingIntent);


    }

    public void stopService()
    {
       //delete ();
       Intent intent = new Intent(Close_Bus.this, gps.class);
       stopService(intent);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your service to stop itself, call

```
stopSelf();
```

and then return.

Is this code in an Activity or what?